# How do you remove the ArcSDE connection from an MXD entirely?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, mxd

I want to remove all connections to the SDE from a number of MXDs that I am using. I have re-set the data sources in each layer in the MXD to a local gdb but still get prompted with the Database connection window asking for user name and password whenever I open the MXD:

[image]

It is still possible to open the MXD but I have to go through several instances of selecting Cancel before it opens.
What is still causing this window to appear?

Comment: You might be better off starting with an empty project. Due to the many-to-many relationship between connections and layers, there is no explicit way to remove a connection from a project. This may have been addressed with changes at 10.5.

Comment: Unfortunately the MXD is generated as a chart template with the SDE connections already set up so I can't start with an empty one.

Comment: You should probably place this information prominently in the question, since it changes the solution (alter the chart template so it doesn't contain connections)

Comment: If anyone is interested this bug was raised with ESRI a few years ago but hasn't been fixed yet - see this discussion with others who have had the same problem: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/166238

Comment: Have you tried using MXD Doctor. I found that once I changed the datasource from an ArcSDE connection to Direct connect, the ArcSDE connection details were still embedded, and was still being prompted for the user/pass. Open the mxd in notepad and search for the instance name (Add a space after each letter). After using MXD doctor, the connection details  was removed, when checked using Notepad (it also reduced the file size).